# Few last lines missing in CSV downloaded

Tags: c#, csv, httpresponse, streamwriter, memorystream

I am using `HttpResponse.BinaryWrite` to create a download a csv file. But I am always getting some last lines missing in csv downloaded. Below I have mentioned my code. I tried by adding bufferSize in `StreamWriter` but nothing seems to work. I am not able to get where the problem is.

```
    public void GetDetailReprot(string groupCode, List<CustomCodeReport> userResponse)
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + groupCode + "." + CommonConstant.CsvFormat);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    writer.WriteLine("TestTakerIdentifier,TestTakerName,Block Name,Item Name,Stimulus,PsuedoWord,UserAnswer,Score");
                    if (userResponse!= null)
                    {
                        foreach (var itemResponse in userResponse)
                        {


                            writer.WriteLine("=\"" + itemResponse.TesrTakerId + "\","
                                             + itemResponse.UserName + ","
                                             + itemResponse.BlockName + ","
                                             + itemResponse.ItemName + ","
                                             + itemResponse.ItemStimulus + ","
                                             + itemResponse.Score);

                            count++;
                        }

                        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Please Help!

**PS:** I tried with `writer.Flush()` but still it's not working. And, Whether `userResponse` list has 100 rows or 500 rows or 1000 rows I am only missing last 4-5 lines in CSV downloded. So how this buffer affects here?

> Is Buffer used here by `StreamWriter` is always just few bytes lesser than
>   what I need?